# prime ideals of $k[x_1,x_2,....]/(x_1,x_2^2, x_3^3,....)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A = k[x_1,x_2,....]/(x_1,x_2^2, x_3^3,....)$ , it's clear that it is not a Noetherian ring as it contains $(x_1)\subset (x_1,x_2）\subset (x_1,x_2,x_3)....$ an infinite ascending chain.

Now I want to study the prime ideal of $A$ which 1 to 1 correspond to the prime ideal containing $(x_1,x_2^2, x_3^3,....)$ the book says it has a single prime ideal, therefore I guess it's sufficient to show that $(x_1,x_2^2, x_3^3,....)$ is a maximal ideal, one standard idea may show the quotient ring isomorphic to a field however I don't know how to prove it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a prime ideal $\mathfrak p \subset A$, then $x_n^n=0\in\mathfrak p$, because $\mathfrak p$ is prime $x_n\in \mathfrak p$ for all $n$. So $(x_1,x_2,...)\subset \mathfrak p$ and $(x_1,x_2,...)$ is a maximal ideal, so $\mathfrak p = (x_1,x_2,...)$. We only used that $\mathfrak p$ is prime, so it is the only prime ideal.

Comment: thank you linkja, this argument also applicable for polynomial ring with finite number of variables correct?

Comment: Why $(x_1,x_2,...)
$ is maximal ideal? I know it's true for finite variable case.

Comment: Yes it is also applicable for finite case. It is maximal because if you take any element  $P$ outside of it, it is of the form $Q+c$ for $Q\in \mathfrak p$ and $c \in k$, then $P-Q = c \in k$ is a unit. (same argument as in the finite case as any polynomial is a finite sum)

Comment: excellent solution thank you linkja